How can I get a Mexican E-mail address with an MX domain, so that I can create an account with the consulate?
I was told that I could create an account to help set everything up for my application for Mexican citizenship based on arental lineage/ancestry. However, when I went on their web site, https://citas.sre.gob.mx/account-register it wants me to use a valid E-mail address, and apparently addresses ending with .com doesn't seem to work. I wonder if it's because they also expect users to already have Mexican phone numbers or E-mail addresses.
Even after selecting the options for visiting their consulates, and that I am wanting to apply for services in Michoacan O Campo, and then selecting Estados Unidos as my current country and nationality, it still wants me to fill out their account information with things that I don't have.
Is there any way around this, or would my only option be to just go to the consulate office near me, with the expectation that it can take a while to get an appointment? I'd really like to do as much of this as I can on-line to help expedite the process, so that all I'd have to do over there is have my fingerprints taken and then receive my Mexican passport.

Not sure if this would be an answer, but I partially figured out why it wasn't allowing me to register. Evidently they don't allow @outlook.com addresses, but they do allow Gmail. That is definitely interesting.

If you were able to register using a gmail address, please post this information as an answer to your own question — that's perfectly proper here.
